# How to read specific node from XML column in stored procedure

Tags: xml, t-sql

I am pulling data from a variety of tables in a tsql stored procedure and one of the fields is an XML column. Each child node of this XML has 2 subnodes: Question and Answer.

The xml structure looks like this:

`<QuestionXML>
    <QuestionCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <Questions>
        <QuestionModel>
          <Question>Color</Question>
          <Answer>Blue</Answer>
        </QuestionModel>
        <QuestionModel>
          <Question>Tall</Question>
          <Answer>False</Answer>
        </QuestionModel>
      </Questions>
    </QuestionCollection>
</QuestionXML>`

I need to find the question node whose name matches the string I pass in, and I would like to retrieve the value of its Answer sibling.

Part 1: I would like to use the required XML syntax that is the equivalent of:
(SELECT Answer FROM Questions Where Question='Color') AS 'COLOR'

Part 2: I would like to select my XML value from an XML column that is the result of a nested SELECT statement.

(
 SELECT Answer

FROM (SELECT F.QuestionXML FROM XMLTable F WHERE F.PIN = @PIN)

Where Question='Color'
) AS 'COLOR'

I am unable to get the XML syntax right.

If anyone could get the XML syntax correct for me, I think I can get Part 2 working on my own.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1, assuming your xml is in an xml variable called @x:

```
SELECT @x.query('//Answer/..[Question="Color"]/Answer')
```

from table:

```
SELECT xmlcolumn.query('//Answer/..[Question="Color"]/Answer/text()') from tablewithXMLcolumn
```

Comment: The 2nd option is very close. It returns "<Color>Blue</Color>" and what I want is just the value, "Blue"